# How to get correct height of Linear layout programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

Here i set the root layout height as **android:layout_height="400dp"**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="400dp"
tools:context=".FirstFragment">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sleep_timer_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline31"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline24"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline23"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline30" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_first"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_first" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My case i want to receive the container height in programmatically(400dp). i try with all methods

```
container.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
container.measure(View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
container.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
val height = measuredHeight
```

and also

```
    val viewTreeObserver: ViewTreeObserver = container.viewTreeObserver
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                container.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                val viewHeight: Int = container.height
                val viewHeight1: Int = container.measuredHeight
            }
        })
     }
```

Nothing works.how to get the container height(400) programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need a method to convert px to dp :

```
public float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    return px / ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

then you can get height of your LinearLayout like this and show that in a Toast:

```
final LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.container);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth(); // this method return px value
            int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); // this method return px value

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "height is : " + convertPixelsToDp(height, MainActivity.this), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```